# What licence or Pricing is required for developing asp.net website using crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, price

I'm developing a website for a company which will be used by both internal users and public users (outside company domain). The website will be using crystal reports for reporting.

I have downloaded "SAP Crystal Reports for VS" from http://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/ but I am not sure what licencing or pricing is required (in context of SAP Crystal Reports).

I have also read out the documents and it's saying that developer version is free, but in the context of above scenario a web site which will be accessed by unlimited users I'm still confused whether the Dev version will be OK or not?

Is there any SAP CR Enterprise version for VS also?

Comment: https://assets.cdn.sap.com/sapcom/docs/2015/05/849f654b-277c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.pdf
This doc was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reporting in ASP.net is free for the majority of applications. To design reports, that is create the rpt files may require a [licensed copy of Crystal Reports](https://www.sapstore.com/solutions/99043/SAP-Crystal-Reports-2016). According to their website at the time of this post, the 2016 version starts at £257.

You can design most reports in the Visual Studio add in, but this designer is limited, and are not intended for use by customers, who are unlikely to have Visual Studio. For example, using images with dynamic formula based URLs is only supported in the full Crystal reports designer and not in the Visual Studio version.

Comment: What I have read so far that if a report is accessed by more than 5 user at a time on your site than you have to purchase a separate license.

Comment: do you have any references? Remember, the report viewer application is simply a way of **viewing** the reports. It would be similar to embedding the Acrobat reader in your web application.

Comment: When I filed this thread I was searching a lot, I'll try my best to find and give you the link.